# Get field and property's type of a class recursively

Tags: c#, generics, recursion, serialization, reflection

Suppose I have a such class:

```
public class Class1 {
    public int x1;
    public Class2 x2;
    public double x3;
}

public class Class2 {
    public int y1;
    private int x2;
}
```

It there any way to get all the type information of **all serializable members** (I think its all public fields and properties without explicit statement to a private member) of `Class1`?

For example, I want to create such a type tree:

```
<Class1>
    <x1>int</x1>
    <x2>Class2</x2>
        <Class2>
            <y1>int</y1>
        </Class2>
    <x3>double</x3>
 </Class1>
```

The tree will expand unless this member is an atomic type (like `int`, `double`, `List` and all system defined type).

#### My idea

I know I can use `reflection` and `deep first search` to do this thing. But I found out things may become complex because the class can be a `generic class`. And I'm concerned whether there is more complex situation than `generic class`.

So there is any better solution than using `reflection` and `deep first search` to create this tree?

Comment: Sure you can do this, and reflection is what it will use. however whats the use case here?

Comment: The use case is that: I want to make sure the definition of `Class1` won't change, then change for `Class1` means only the `type` and `name` (If the member has a `XmlElement` attribute, then its name should be the `ElementName` ) of all `serializable` members won't change. So I want to store all the type and name information of class1.

Comment: Reflection is perfectly fit your needs. Why don't you use it? And what is complexity with generic classes?

Comment: @Caesium oh so this is to stop dirty little fingers changing the class. Chuck it in an assembly or nuget in release.. anyway i think your question is how to deal with generic types when reflecting, and outputting the generic type parameters

Comment: @TheGeneral I don’t know what means chuck it in an assembly... Can you make it clear?

Comment: @Caesium It means "move it in a different library project". You may also strong-name it.

Comment: Yeah you can put t in a class library, or use an interface/contract. however if you really need to go down the road of reflection, there is many questions answered on enumerating all the properties of a class (and sub properties)

Comment: @vasily.sib I know reflection can meets my needs. Just want to find out more elegant solution. Because there are many boundary cases for class like generic classes, it's not easy to cover all boundary cases.

Comment: Well there is a more complex problem where your classes are self referencing. This could be something like a "parent" property on a tree structure.  Even something like DateTime has a Now property that is also of type DateTime. Using a depth first recursive reflector needs to handle such cases workout going off and crashing once the stack overflows. Also, your planned serialisation format would not cope with that parent example and would be quite inefficient as your common classes will be declared under lots of nodes.

Comment: @AdamG yes there is such a situation. I planed to use a hashset<Type> to recording all visited types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this, and there is'nt too many boundary there is only generics, there are easy ways to get the generic type parameters and you will have to recurse them.

However i think you are trying to solve this the wrong way.

If i understand you correctly, you want to protect against serialization issues. I would come at this from a different angle.

1. Decorate you classes with interfaces to insure a contract.
2. And/order put your classes/interfaces in a Class Library where they are less likely to be bumper, or even take a step further and nuget them.
3. If you are truly worried about serialization issues, use a contract based serializer like DataContracts, that breaks if changed and can be versioned.

**Update**

> 1. users owns the classes which need to be serialized.
> 2. I used XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize it.
> 3. The problem I want to solve is:
>
>    - First, user defined the Class1 like above, and it's
>        deployed to both machine A and machine B.
>    - Then users added a public
>        field x into Class1, the deployment of machine A is quicker than B. so
>        machine A recongnized the newly added x. But machine B's deployment is
>        slower, so machine B don't know x, then the serialization will broke
>        for machine B.
>    - So now I want to make sure no more changes of the
>        classes passed to my serializer.

Then you need reflection, there is no library i can think of that does what you want. You will have to dig into generic types and recuse, end of story

Comment: 1. users owns the classes which need to be serialized. 2. I used `XmlSerializer` to serialize and deserialize it. 3. The problem I want to solve is: First, user defined the `Class1` like above, and it's deployed to both machine A and machine B. Then users added a public field `x` into `Class1`, the deployment of machine A is quicker than B. so machine A recongnized the newly added `x`. But machine B's deployment is slower, so machine B don't know `x`, then the serialization will broke for machine B. So now I want to make sure no more changes of the classes passed to my serializer.

Comment: @Caesium updated, however(and unfortunately) your original question is to not use reflection, this is the best answer i can give without writing reflection code

Comment: If the only boundary case is generic type, then I think the problem is not so complex...Thank you.

Comment: @Caesium yeah if you have problems with the reflection code, just ask a new question, and it will be sorted in a flash

Answer (score 0):

I believe that FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers will return **all serializable members**, as you originally asked in your question.